# SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

In MySQL I can do :

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

The output is like this :

```
...

Number of rows inserted 52629, updated 104255, deleted 52135, read 156400
    
0 inserts/s, 60 updates/s, 0 deletes/s, 0 reads/s

...
```

This means that my current query is doing about 60 updates per second.

Is there a similar query/tool in SQL Server to know how many updates/insert/select/delete I am doing per second while my query is still running?

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_sessions` has columns for reads and writes, use your `@@spid` to match. `SET STATISTICS IO ON` before the query gives you a summary at the end.

Comment: Also see `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`